# How to make it work newer version of jaxb-api.jar with OC4J server together?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, oc4j, java-5

When I try the code block:

```
JAXBContext jc = 
    JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbRootElement.class,jaxbElement.getClass());
```

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;
```

How to tell OC4J server to use my own JAXB-API.jar instead of its own older version?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution:
As OC4J has java 1.5 embedded with it, I needed to find the missing extra jars for the JAXBContext usage.I Put jars in lib directory and add them to my server.xml
Here the missing jars:

- jaxb-impl-2.2.jar
- activation-1.1.1.jar
- jaxb-api-2.2.jar